# MoveIt: Error: Action client not connected

Tags: ros, moveit, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-kinetic, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On running move it for my custom robotic arm i am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] [1534930610.891287885, 28.494000000]: Action client not connected: uvbot_v1/arm_joint_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ERROR] [1534930610.891287885, 28.494000000]: Action client not connected: uvbot_v1/arm_joint_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

Can anyone explain how to setup action client? The tutorials are a bit sketchy.

---

Edit: these are the active action servers:

```
/execute_trajectory/goal
/move_group/goal
/pickup/goal
/place/goal
/uvbot_v1/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
```

is there a conflict btw execute_trajectory and follow_joint_trajectory

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301196/moveit:-error:-action-client-not-connected/) by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to make sure that the MoveIt cofiguration (I'm assuming you're trying to configure MoveIt here, seeing your other questions) corresponds to whatever namespaces and names your action server(s) is (are) using.

That can sometimes be a bit difficult to figure out, but a simple way to get that information (in lieu of a command line actionlib tool) is something like:

```
rostopic list | grep -i goal
```

That should provide you with a list of online action servers.

If you've only got your robot driver (or `ros_control` or `gazebo_ros_control` stack) running, you should probably see only one or two results.

One of those will be the FollowJointTrajectory action server (you can use `rostopic info /name/of/the/action/topic` to find out).

Now use that name in your MoveIt controller configuration file.

For more information, see the [Low Level Controllers](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/controller_configuration/controller_configuration_tutorial.html) page in the MoveIt documentation. That should make things more clear. Pay attention to the [Debugging Information](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/controller_configuration/controller_configuration_tutorial.html#debugging-information) section: it contains an explanation of the differences between the `name` and `action_ns` fields, which typically confuse people.

---

Edit:

> these are the active action servers:

> ```
> /execute_trajectory/goal
> ```

This is probably the one you need (but this is a guess, as I don't know how you've setup your system).

> ```
> /uvbot_v1/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
> ```

This is most likely not a server, but MoveIt's client that has created a publisher for that topic (as part of its action client). But as no one is listening, you get the error message that you already showed.

> is there a conflict btw execute_trajectory and follow_joint_trajectory

I don't understand your question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on 2018-08-22**:
Do I need feedback from motor to complete the execution? How can i do this in simulation?
I am getting this error:
`Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1 seconds.`
I get that this is because the robot is not getting info about current state, how to proceed?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
These are completely different issues, and not related to the configuration of the action client at all.

If you already have questions about these issues, update those if necessary. If not, post a new question.

Posting follow-up questions in comments like this is not a good practice.

**Comment by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on 2018-08-22**:
Okay I'll do that. I did not know about this guideline.
Anyways I've solved this issue by modifying the moveit trajectory execution launch file. Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:\

> Anyways I've solved this issue by modifying the moveit trajectory execution launch file.

the launch file?

Not the controller configuration yaml?

**Comment by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on 2018-08-22**:
Yes the launch file, as the name of the controller was different in both the files.